# Trying to hide an element on regular layout but have it appear in mobile layout

Tags: css

Have a flexbox layout whose code is a bit convoluted ... there's an image that I want to have it appear only in the mobile layout but not in the regular layout.

How do I do that? I know there's `display:none` but if I put that in the regular code, it doesn't appear at all in the mobile layout.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to JS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry if I don’t fully understand, but can’t you just use a CSS media query to apply `display:none` only on mobile resolutions?  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @divibisan, yes I can. However, the question is rather the inverse of that. I want it invisible in regular layout but visible in mobile layout.

Comment: @divibisan, as things stand, I don't know how to have it appear in mobile css layout when it's invisible in the regular css.

Comment: Couldn’t you have it set to `display:none` in the normal code, then, and have the media query apply `display:block`?

Comment: @divibisan, just figured that out right now. it didn't work earlier for some reason hence why I asked. But tried it again right now, and it worked!

Comment: hm, don't know if I should delete the question or not.

Comment: I’m not sure of the etiquette. I made it an answer so you can either accept it or delete

Comment: @divibisan, ok dokey, will accept your answer so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you set the image to `display:none` in the normal code, then, and have a media query apply `display:block` on mobile resolutions?